# Why does the test statistic of a 2 Sample K-S test change drastically when noise is added to samples?

Tags: r, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I believe I have gone through all 2 Sample K-S test related posts here, but I could not see the answer to my problem. At this point, I don't know whether the problem is related to a bug in the function that I am using in R or to my lack of understanding of the statistical test I am running. Therefore, I apologize in advance if this is not the correct medium to discuss this problem. Any guidance will be much appreciated.

I have some pairs of vectors of expenditure data and I want to compare each pair within itself with 2 Sample K-S test to see whether it is plausible to assume that they are drawn from the same population. However, these vectors include many zeros (no expenditures) and sometimes same values may appear more than once. K-S Test is based on the assumption that the underlying distribution is continuous and that this assumption is used in calculating the test-statistic. Ties in these vectors violate this assumption and thus produce a warning (i.e. `cannot compute correct p-values with ties`). Moreover, the results I receive are highly counter-intuitive (i.e. if I visually compare these vectors by Kernel Densities or empirical CDFs, I see that the pairs that are very different to each other may have higher p-values than the pairs that are barely different to naked eye).

I assumed that if I add some noise to the data, KS test might function properly and produce plausible results. So I used `jitter()` in R function to add some noise to these vector pairs. I made sure that the noise added is very very small (I set `amount = 0.000001`). I would expect to reach always the same test statistic and same p-value with these noise-added vectors since these random noises are very small - they are drawn from a uniform distribution within (-0.000001,0.000001). But much to my surprise, the test statistic can change from time to time much more than I expected. (For instance it can be 0.1232734 and 0.1356571 in different runs.) Even small changes in the test statistic lead to big changes in the p-value, which is not ideal for me at all. I would like to develop a robust way of comparing these vectors.

The test statistic in this case is the supremum of the distance between empirical CDFs of the two vector. And to me, it seems like this noise sould not effect this statistic, at least the first couple decimal points. Am I missing something here?

Comment: is there consistency in noise's impact? say, when you decrease the magnitude of noise, does the test statistic move consistently in one direction or converge to something?

Comment: @ak no there isn't